# using urllib and beautifulsoup to find values inside "hidden" tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

i want to know if it is possible to display the values of hidden tags. im using urllib and beautifulsoup but i cant seem to get what i want.

the html code im using is written below: (saved as **hiddentry.html**)

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //change hidden elem value
        function changeValue()
        {
            document.getElementById('hiddenElem').value = 'hello matey!';
        }

        //this will verify if i have successfully changed the hiddenElem's value
        function printHidden()
        {
            document.getElementById('displayHere').innerHTML = document.getElementById('hiddenElem').value;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="hiddenDiv" style="position: absolute; left: -1500px">
        <!--i want to find the value of this element right here-->
        <span id="hiddenElem"></span>
    </div>

    <span id="displayHere"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        changeValue();
        printHidden();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

what i want to print is the value of element with id **hiddenElem**.
to do this i tried using urllib and beautifulsoup combo. the code i used is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib

mysite = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost/hiddentry.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(mysite)
print soup.prettify()
print '\n\n'

areUthere = soup.find(id="hiddenElem").find(text=True)
print areUthere
```

what i am getting as output though is **None**.
any ideas? is what i am trying to accomplish even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beautifulsoup parses the html that it gets from the server.  If you want to see generated values, you need to somehow execute the embedded javascript on the page *before* passing the string to beautifulsoup.  Once you run the javascript, you'll pass the modified DOM html to beautifulsoup.

As far as browser emulation:

- [this combo from the creator of jQuery looks interesting](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/)
- SO question [bringing the browser to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768717/non-browser-emulation-of-javascript-is-it-possible)
- and SO question [headless internet browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)

Using browser emulation, you should be able to pull down the base HTML, run browser emulation to execute the javascript, and then take the modified DOM HTML and jam it into beautifulsoup.

Comment: how can i do that sir? ive tried using setInterval for both functions. im still learning my way through web design. if you can point me in the right direction to solving this that would be superb

Comment: gave it a quick scan and it made my nose bleed. so basically what i want to accomplish is too complex huh? i thought i would be easy. T_T

Comment: It would be easy without javascript

Comment: i thought beautifulsoup was my panacea to web scraping. javascript is a party pooper.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is an xml parsing library specialized for html parsing. Parsing xml and html has nothing to do with executing javascript. I don't see what problem you cannot solve with this parser, though. It seems like the information you want is just in another part of the document. The only time the data you want is outside of the document would be if the js executes an ajax call. In which case, use a regex to get the url of the ajax call out of the text of the script tag and open it before parsing with a json or xml parser.

Comment: @marr759 that has got me confused as well sir! my understanding is that the value i want to get is still in the document, albeit hidden. but my understanding of all this is pretty basic so i did not know how to proceed