# PHP + JavaScript + Cron

Tags: javascript, php, cron, google-visualization

I am attempting to get data from MySQL and render it using Google charts via Javascript, get a base64 encoded image that i AJAX post to anotehr PHP script to save. This works fine.

My problem is I need this to run as a cron job to generate the chart once per week. When the cron runs the JS does not execute because it is not in the browser. I need a suggestion on how to handle this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768717/non-browser-emulation-of-javascript-is-it-possible

Comment: [Maybe this?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-charts)

Answer (score 0):

There few options:

1. Use this extension http://php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php and run js code in PHP.
2. Use some tool that runs a headless browser that does a request to PHP server. Pick one from the list https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers. Use cron to run that tool

Comment: Is phantomjs maintained these days? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

Comment: @zerkms That was just an example of a tool. Updated answer.