# headless browser for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, headless-browser

I am developing full ajax web app. So I need to develop google crawlable app, also I must create snapshot for googlebot.

Do you know headless browser works with javascript and ajax for ASP.NET ?

I found XBrowser but right now it hasn't JavaScript support.

sorry for my English :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASP.NET I would suggest [WatiN](http://watin.org/). It was originally designed for automated integration testing but would work great for making snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

See here: [headless internet browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)

and here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: He said ASP.NET. htmlUnit is Java.

Comment: @Grinn, ASP.NET is the framework the website was developed in. A headless browser is not confined to the developer's framework, only the platform on which the browser is run. That would be like saying that the Konqueror browser cannot view ASP.NET websites because it is developed for Linux.

Comment: @Jordan I get the impression he wants to automate the browser from inside .Net, not capture a screenshot of a .Net site

Comment: @Basic I got the idea that he would be okay with using the Java based XBrowser if it had JavaScript support. But I didn't realize there was more than one XBrowser, and he's probably refering to the .NET based one. He's also not trying to capture a "screenshot", he's trying to create a "snapshot" (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot).