# Web Scraping pages with javascript content on a shared hosting

Tags: php, ruby, perl, web-scraping, shared-hosting

I would like to scrape web pages that load content dynamically with Javascript or similar.

Something like a headless browser, that I could use on a Linux Shared Host without X.

I can use PHP, Perl, Ruby or Python.

Do any of you know some framework/headless browser that can help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [headless internet browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't get an inexpensive VPS and install whatever you want on it? Shared hosting is usually a terrible place to run intensive operations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to control the browser if you need to simulate key presses or clicks in order to get the content to load.

For a headless browser, there are some listed here: [headless internet browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)

Answer (score 1):

See library [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.029/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod)

***Synopsis:***

```
use WWW::Scripter;

$w = new WWW::Scripter;
$w->use_plugin('Javascript');
$w->get('http://some.site.com/that/uses/javascript');
$w->content; # returns the HTML content, possibly modified by scripts
$w->eval('alert("Hello from JavaScript")');
$w->document->getElementsByTagName('div')->[0]->...
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Perl [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) in Perl. This module has numerous methods that can perform web browser like functions. Below is a Sample code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;

my $username = "admin";
my $password = "welcome1";  
my $outpath  = "/home/data/output";
my $fromday = 7;
my $url  = "https://www.myreports.com/tax_report.php";
my $name = "tax_report";
my $outfile = "$outpath/$name.html";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(noproxy =>'0');  

$mech->get($url);
$mech->field(login => "$username");
$mech->field(passwd => "$password");

$mech->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$mech->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

$mech->click_button(value=>"Login now");

my $response = $mech->content();

print "Generating report: $name...\n";

open (OUT, ">>$outfile")|| die "Cannot create report file $outfile";
print OUT "$response";
close OUT;
```

In-case you want to handle Javascripts in the web-page (which you want to scrape), you can have a look at [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm), but this may require installing the [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) plugin for Mozilla.

Comment: W:M:Firefox is not a headless browser, it very much requires X.