# Parsing links where Javascript is generating HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the past, when I've used BeautifulSoup and lxml to parse webpages, it's been pretty easy because links all looked like this: `<a href="www.website.com">Website</a>`. However, I've encountered some webpages where links appear in the browser but not in the page source.

For example, on [this Edmunds.com page](http://www.edmunds.com/subaru/brz/2013/long-term-road-test/2013-subaru-brz-its-just-fun-on-a-back-road.html), the `Past Long-Term Road Tests` section looks like this:

[`1991 Acura NSX`](http://www.edmunds.com/acura/nsx/1991/long-term-road-test/)
[`2011 Acura TSX Sport Wagon`](http://www.edmunds.com/acura/tsx-sport-wagon/2011/long-term-road-test/)
`...`

---

However, the source code for the `Past Long Long-Term Road Tests` section of [the page](http://www.edmunds.com/subaru/brz/2013/long-term-road-test/2013-subaru-brz-its-just-fun-on-a-back-road.html) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PAGESETUP.addControl(function() {
function linksObj(){
var elink = "|acura|nsx|1991|long-term-road-test|"; //generates edmunds.com/acura/nsx/1991/long-term-road-test/
this.link0 = {anchor:elink,label:"1991 Acura NSX"};
var elink = "|acura|tsx-sport-wagon|2011|long-term-road-test|"; //generates edmunds.com/acura/tsx-sport-wagon/1991/long-term-road-test/
this.link1 = {anchor:elink,label:"2011 Acura TSX Sport Wagon"};
...
}
var links_obj = new linksObj();
var links_container = document.getElementById('links_list_offpage2');
var more_link = "";
var more_link_text = "";
var elinks = new EDMUNDS.linksList(links_obj, links_container,more_link, more_link_text);
}, 'low');
</script>
```

The Javascript line `var elink = "|acura|nsx|1991|long-term-road-test|";` gets expanded to `edmunds.com/acura/nsx/1991/long-term-road-test` in the browser.

---

**Tools like BeautifulSoup and lxml aren't finding the links that are generated in Javascript. How can I parse these links?**

Comment: Copy the `EDMUNDS.linkList` function I guess

Answer (score 2):

Use a [headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser) such as [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to run the page's JavaScript, and you should have no problem scrapting the JS-altered DOM.