# Embedding a web browser within a php script

Tags: php, javascript

In my project I have to do some screen scrapping.The source pages return data after executing the javascript  embedded within them.In my php script I fetch the page using file_get_contents() and as usual,it returns the page simply as text.My question is that,is there a way to get the final output from the webpage (the output after executing javascript).

I know some of you might suggest embedding a webbrowser inside and using that to execute the page.But how to do that?.Is there a working browser available.Or is there executable non GUI versions of opensource browsers such as chromium,so that I can run it as a CGI script or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to have some real browser like client for this, php alone won't cut it. For automation purposes you are most likely want a "headless" (without gui) browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (the new hotness).  Check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/1515540)