# Download autoloading web pages

Tags: javascript, html, download

This is bugging me, because I'm a complete newbie in web interaction:

How can I download a web page that is **dynamically autoloading**?

For instance, twitter's feed, facebook's wall, etc. The only restriction is that I'd like to do this on a client, with a background job, **no browser involved**. I'd prefer to use C#, but any language is completely welcome.

Comment: You want a web page without browser ?? :O

Comment: Yes, no browser. Something like "wget --dynamicoption $somepage" would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to achieve your goal using a headless browser like *phantomJS* as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856036/save-html-output-of-page-after-execution-of-the-pages-javascript).

Also check if the service you want to get data from offers you an API, which is always a better solution! Accessing websites in an automated way is no good practice.