# C# Get full html document from site

Tags: html, url, asynchronous, download, document

I tried to use `GetStringAsync`

```csharp
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
  richTextBox1.Text = html.ToString();
}
```

and `DownloadString`

```csharp
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string webData = wc.DownloadString(url);
richTextBox1.Text = webData;
```

But it doesn't give me full html document like Google Chrome <kbd>F12</kbd>. How can I get full html code of url using C#?

Need this url: http://poeplanner.com/ but it doesn't show me even a single table when Chrome <kbd>F12</kbd> does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the code you don't see is a code that added with javascript. So you need use a browser program to get this code too.

This app will run the javascript too and you can ask from it the final html.

If I'm right, try to use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

[Related question on PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16856036/863110)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect ^^