# Get DOM after javascript runs java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I need to get the contents of a URL as a String, but the page this url points to has javascript that runs on page load that manipulates the DOM. How can I retrieve the HTML with the javascript DOM manipulation included? Is something like Selenium the right option? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: You'll probably want a headless browser. Some suggestions are listed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/814929.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

Use the [pause command](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause)

And then use `driver.getPageSource()`