# Server side ASP.NET driven templating system w/ logic (similar to JsRender)

Tags: asp.net, templates, mustache, jsrender, headless-browser

I'm looking for a templating library, similar to [JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender), that runs server side on .NET.

[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) is a non-starter, because it's mostly logic-less. We need something with functionality similar to `{{if}}`, `{{else}}`, `{{for array}}`, and the ability to call custom functions within the template.

In theory, I could probably use JsRender on the server by reading output from [WatiN](http://watin.org/) or any [other .NET headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)... but I thought I'd put the question out there in case I can bypass the headless browser part.

Any ideas?

Comment: asp.net MVC? NancyFX?

Comment: Certainly a lot of folks are using JsRender on the server - including outlook.com...

Comment: Also - note that JsRender doesn't need either a DOM or jQuery. It does pure string-based rendering. It just needs a javascript engine.

Comment: @TimBJames asp.NET WebForms.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I'm storing all templates in a database. Not sure I can store a razor template in a db, then bind to an object.

Comment: @BorisMoore Interesting. Didn't think that was possible. Any .NET javascript engines you'd recommend? Considering http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DavidBudiac: I haven't personally worked on that scenario myself, but the two I know about are: outlook.com is using chakra ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249552(v=vs.94).aspx), and there are others using node.js...

Comment: mustache-sharp at: [link]https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp.

Supports your {{if}}, {{else}} etc. 

Just add your choice of loading and buffering of the html. Db or Text files are both fine.