# Browser to Run Javascript but Not Render

Tags: javascript

What I want may seem odd but I really need it.

I want my javascript file to run in browser. But i just need the source code of the page after it has made DOM manipulations. Don't tell me run it, select all page and click view source because it generates too many elements that browser can't render and it crashes. I just want text output of the changed document. Is it possible with browsers? If not can i find a javascript engine or something similar anywhere?

Comment: It is possible with phantomjs.

Comment: That would be a [headless browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser). PhantomJS is one such option.