# defining specific PHP curl options for specific web page retrieval

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to scrape this web page: [SiriusXMU](http://www.siriusxm.com/siriusxmu) to get the "now playing" information. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
    $timeout = 60;
    $url = 'http://www.siriusxm.com/siriusxmu';
    $agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0';
    $referer = 'http://www.siriusxm.com/channellineup/';

    $header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    //$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    //$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);//The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);//The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);//An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);//TRUE to include the header in the output.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);//The contents of the "Referer: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');//The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);//TRUE to automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);//TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);//The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);//TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure. 
    //      
    $result = curl_exec($ch);//Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.
    curl_close($ch);
```

I've been studying the HTTP headers that my browser sends which successfully enables the web page's "On the Air" section which shows what's now playing. However, when I simulate those headers with curl, the "One the Air" section of the web page returns "Sorry, program information is not available for the selected platform."

Firefox AddOn HttpFox shows the following for the main page:

```
00:00:03.904    0.163   1524    209 GET 200 text/html   http://www.siriusxm.com/siriusxmu

(Request-Line)  GET /siriusxmu HTTP/1.1
Host    www.siriusxm.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://www.siriusxm.com/channellineup/
Cookie  mmcore.tst=0.557; mmid=-318486443%7CBQAAAAo2JYEzEgwAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.pd=111492824%7CBQAAAAoBQjYlgTMSDPt9EvUCAJ3zFneyeNJIDwAAAIQ4RsgceNJIAAAAAP//////////ABB3d3cuc2lyaXVzeG0uY29tAhIMAgAAAAAAAAAAAAD///////////////8AAAAAAAFF; mmcore.srv=cg5.usw; __utma=1.1327546933.1434659528.1434659528.1434723665.2; __utmz=1.1434659528.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); s_nr=1434723821271-Repeat; s_vnum=1435723200051%26vn%3D2; s_lastvisit=1434723660883; s_vi=[CS]v1|2AC1956485078C76-6000010E20030C67[CE]; mm_pc=%7B%22vehiclenewness%22%3A%22new%22%2C%22PC2%22%3A%22%22%7D; sxm_platform=xm; __utmv=1.|5=serviceType=xm=1; _hjUserId=86ab277e-6c63-4dd1-975c-3424e32502e6; __insp_slim=1434659556045; __insp_wid=800165747; __insp_nv=true; __insp_ref=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaXJpdXN4bS5jb20vc3RyZWFtaW5n; __insp_norec_sess=true; _hjIncludedInSample=1; __utmc=1; s_cc=true; SC_LINKS=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sv_sid=797366592635; QSI_HistorySession=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fstreaming~1434659533837%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fchannellineup%2F%23~1434659556190%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fsiriusxmu~1434659575429; s_invisit=true; __utmb=1.8.10.1434723665
Connection  keep-alive
```

and the following when requesting the javascript for the "One the Air" part:

```
00:00:05.293    1.186   1609    (137)   GET 304 text/javascript http://www.siriusxm.com/static/app/js/sxm-channel-ontheair.js

(Request-Line)  GET /static/app/js/sxm-channel-ontheair.js HTTP/1.1
Host    www.siriusxm.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://www.siriusxm.com/siriusxmu
Cookie  mmcore.tst=0.557; mmid=-318486443%7CBQAAAAo2JYEzEgwAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.pd=111492824%7CBQAAAAoBQjYlgTMSDPt9EvUCAJ3zFneyeNJIDwAAAIQ4RsgceNJIAAAAAP//////////ABB3d3cuc2lyaXVzeG0uY29tAhIMAgAAAAAAAAAAAAD///////////////8AAAAAAAFF; mmcore.srv=cg5.usw; __utma=1.1327546933.1434659528.1434659528.1434723665.2; __utmz=1.1434659528.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); s_nr=1434723821271-Repeat; s_vnum=1435723200051%26vn%3D2; s_lastvisit=1434723660883; s_vi=[CS]v1|2AC1956485078C76-6000010E20030C67[CE]; mm_pc=%7B%22vehiclenewness%22%3A%22new%22%2C%22PC2%22%3A%22%22%7D; sxm_platform=xm; __utmv=1.|5=serviceType=xm=1; _hjUserId=86ab277e-6c63-4dd1-975c-3424e32502e6; __insp_slim=1434659556045; __insp_wid=800165747; __insp_nv=true; __insp_ref=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaXJpdXN4bS5jb20vc3RyZWFtaW5n; __insp_norec_sess=true; _hjIncludedInSample=1; __utmc=1; s_cc=true; SC_LINKS=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sv_sid=797366592635; QSI_HistorySession=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fstreaming~1434659533837%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fchannellineup%2F%23~1434659556190%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriusxm.com%2Fsiriusxmu~1434659575429; s_invisit=true; __utmb=1.8.10.1434723665
Connection  keep-alive
If-Modified-Since   Fri, 22 May 2015 02:06:57 GMT
If-None-Match   "ab841364-8501-516a21d70499b"
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

The web server is determining something invalid about my curl request and not enabling the "On the Air" javascript stuff and just says "Sorry, program information is not available for the selected platform."

How can I get curl to work properly and emulate my browser and thus return valid web page results from this web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you'll need to run a client that has a JavaScript interpreter.

The HTML includes the following:

```
<div id="on-the-air-unavailable"><p>Sorry, program information is not available for the selected platform.</p></div>
```

The JS includes the following (not together):

```
$("#on-the-air-unavailable").hide();
$("#on-the-air-unavailable").show();
```

To have the JavaScript interact with the HTML you will need to run them together.

There are some headless HTTP clients that have JS interpreters or browser automation tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) that you may be able to use.

Comment: Please suggest some headless HTTP clients that have JS interpreters: it appears that SimpleTest's PHP scriptable web browser (http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html) does not include a JS interpreter. EDIT: I found some in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/5006730