# Selenium Java New Tab in Chrome - won't open , keeps opening URL`s in same tab

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Aca\\desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        // Initialize driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //Maximize browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Go to URL
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        //Set timeout
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Open new tab  – May be you are stuck here
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
        //Go to URL
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        //Set new tab timeout
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    }
}
```

I am trying to open a new tab, leaving the previous tab opened .. 
I can't get a new tab opened. It keeps opening URL`s in the same tab.. I also tried using Actions.

Comment: check this if it helps - http://qaperspective.blogspot.in/2016/09/open-new-tab-using-Selenium-WebDriver.html

Comment: Yeah Thanks, this works : ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");

Comment: Glad it worked, It will work on all modern browsers as they support javascript out-of-box. For headless browser, you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser/814929#814929

Comment: Can you use any other hotkeys? For example Ctrl+N? I have the same issue, but for me no hotkeys are working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the driver to the new tab. In Chrome its done like switching windows

```
String tabHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");

// switch to the new window
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(tabHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

// close the new tab and switch back to the old one
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabHandle);
```

As a side note, `implicitlyWait` is defined for the driver, not tab/window. No need to define it again after opening the new tab.

Comment: It still opens (in this case gmail) in the same tab.. Im using Chrome version 54.0.2840.71 and selenium 3.0.1..

Comment: This worked , and your switch works : ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");

Comment: And chromedriver version?

Comment: @monami Its doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with chromedriver itself. See [the related bug submitted](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1554)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to open new tab in Chrome with Selenium Java.

```
     package com.sample;



        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

        public class NewWindow {

            public static void main (String[] args){
                System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
                options.addArguments("disable-arguments");


                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("https://www.google.com");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to change the focus of the driver to the new tab before navigating.

Try this after opening a new tab:

```
driver.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t"));
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); //Get tabs
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //Navigate to new tab
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com"); //Navigate within new tab
driver.close(); //Close the tab when done
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); //Navigate to original tab
```

Comment: I don`t think switching is the problem , because new tab is never opened in the first place..    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t"); - doesn`t work

Comment: Ahh ok. I will edit my answer to include how to open a new tab

Comment: Solved it with JS : ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');"); But what if i cant use JS , is there a way to open a new tab without JS ?