# How can I get `location.href` redirected page in node.js `request` module?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, request, redirect

If I get a page which shows waiting message and it contains markup like this:

```
<body onload="location.href='redirect.html';">
```

This waiting page and redirect.html both get `200 OK` in broswer,

but `request` module seems like only follow 3xx redirect in HTTP response.

How can I get `redirect.html` by using `request` module?

Comment: The `request` module alone isn't meant to do that. It's only defined to understand HTTP, not HTML or to evaluate client-side JavaScript. For the latter, there are numerous [headless browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser) that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can just parse the new href for example via regex and do a new request.