# Programatically check if web resource is loaded to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, bash, frontend

How can I check if website is loading, for example, jquery, or downloading an image from imgur? I can inspect this traffic in Firefox/Chrome, but I would like to have a programmatic way of doing so, preferably in bash.

I know I can curl the contents, but sometimes some external stuff loads all kinds of things and I want to check which content/script/resource did go through.

[image: Like this]

Comment: To do that properly you need to mimic the behavior of a browser to account for resources loaded via script, see [headless internet browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of external libraries like jQuery in your example, you can check for the existence of global variables found only in that library:

```
if (jQuery) {
    // this resource has been loaded
}
```

or

```
if (someLibraryVariable === 'undefined') {
    // if this is undefined, this resource using this variable is not loaded on the page
}
```

If jQuery, or whatever your test variable is, has not been loaded to the page, this will throw an error.

You could also read the `src` of any script tags. In the case of images, you'd have to read the `src` of image tags.