# Is there a way to get a HTML as Browser will render it, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, server-rendering

I'm looking for a way to render an HTML, and get the whole document source of if after a browser (let's say firefox), renders it...
The thing is that I'm using some numbering, just the looks, such as CSS `::before` or javascript to highlight code blocks, or render Mathjax.

My question is, if there is a way to do a "server render" to do that? If so how?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a headless browser.

Comment: I have never heard about that but sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/ but it seems the project is suspended

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/headless-browsers/ read that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/9638388

Comment: I hope I knew the term before, or even that that was a thing, thanks, this was so useful I got super excited about all the problemes this solves.

Comment: jsdom is another option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

Comment: Phanthomjs is superceded by Chrome Headless. Have a look at puppeteer for instance which is a library to easily control Chrome Headless from node.js

Comment: I have a question on how to choose one, I just want to run the CSS so I can use counter and enumerate, putting prefixes, render Katex (something like mathjax), and code highlighting. Should I open a new question or could some one directly to the simplest one, I'm alrady working with python, to do it, but I don't mind moving to node in case of that...

Answer (score 0):

Using a webdriver like selenium, just open the file or URI, that you are amming to render, and get the source of the page, after it renders.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(URI)
source = driver.page_source
```