# urlopen not getting all the data from web (python)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib2

i am trying to download pictures from a site. I figured out that the problem why i cant find the picture URL is immediatelly in the beginning of the code.

I have a problem with that urlopen is downloading a diffrerent HTML than i get in browser.

The site is [here](https://ceskamincovna.cz/stribrna-mince-na-kolech---skoda-felicia-proof-1493-11549-d/). When i look at HTML in browser, i can see this part:

[HTML in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u87CS.png)

```
<a href="#" data-trigger="cmg-rotate-big">
            <img src="/image/product/eca412b9-9484-4046-8bee-8400fde1d5fe/?width=400" alt="" data-cm-index="0" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
            <img src="/image/product/014a128e-fa7b-4817-9d76-7bdf296de8de/?width=400" alt="" data-cm-index="1" style="width: 0px; height: 400px; margin-left: 200px; opacity: 0.5;">
          </a>
```

But by the code

```
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

the same part is only

```
<a data-trigger="cmg-rotate-big" href="#">
<img alt="" data-cm-index="0" src=""/>
<img alt="" data-cm-index="1" src=""/>
</a>
```

So i can extract the SRC of the image because its missing.. where is the problem please?

Thank you!

Comment: You need something that simulates the Javascript code that populates these DOM elements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/4570170).

Comment: I will try selenium, thanks for this idea :)

Comment: Selenium works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The src href is in there. No need to simulate javascript.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://ceskamincovna.cz/stribrna-mince-na-kolech---skoda-felicia-proof-1493-11549-d/'

response = requests.get(url) 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
for img in imgs:
    if '/image/product/' in img['src']:
        print (img['src'])
```

**Output:**

```
/image/product/eca412b9-9484-4046-8bee-8400fde1d5fe/?width=250
/image/product/014a128e-fa7b-4817-9d76-7bdf296de8de/?width=250
/image/product/0ec5b392-0f8a-4013-a448-a1b82578c008/?width=250
/image/product/9bc26462-5f11-4994-be6e-fcde1d97c5f3/?width=250
/image/product/7da1f235-f322-4a57-b0ca-07964f0a7d37/?width=250
/image/product/bd781b17-8482-4a4f-80f3-5fa55b9bc4c1/?width=250
/image/product/f5d4ade9-cac0-4c15-a935-da125b408da1/?width=250
/image/product/f4d6fb41-af72-4510-a70c-0a9893656e93/?width=250
/image/product/6136afe7-7444-42cd-858b-af66ca4ca6de/?width=140
/image/product/a459eb25-dd12-446a-9517-341d128c9571/?width=140
```

If you want the width = 400:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://ceskamincovna.cz/stribrna-mince-na-kolech---skoda-felicia-proof-1493-11549-d/'

response = requests.get(url) 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
for img in imgs:
    if '/image/product/' in img['src']:
        print (img['src'].split('?width=')[0] + '?width=400')
```

**Output:**

```
/image/product/eca412b9-9484-4046-8bee-8400fde1d5fe/?width=400
/image/product/014a128e-fa7b-4817-9d76-7bdf296de8de/?width=400
/image/product/0ec5b392-0f8a-4013-a448-a1b82578c008/?width=400
/image/product/9bc26462-5f11-4994-be6e-fcde1d97c5f3/?width=400
/image/product/7da1f235-f322-4a57-b0ca-07964f0a7d37/?width=400
/image/product/bd781b17-8482-4a4f-80f3-5fa55b9bc4c1/?width=400
/image/product/f5d4ade9-cac0-4c15-a935-da125b408da1/?width=400
/image/product/f4d6fb41-af72-4510-a70c-0a9893656e93/?width=400
/image/product/6136afe7-7444-42cd-858b-af66ca4ca6de/?width=400
/image/product/a459eb25-dd12-446a-9517-341d128c9571/?width=400
```

Comment: I need to get a picture, that ends with "width=400" :)

Comment: Then just manipulate the string. It's just a parameter to display the image. you can change that to width=400

Comment: Good idea if the rest of the file is same, but i have solved this by selenium :) Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, Selenium is a viable solution too since it is dynamically created content.